# ShowcaseView is not centered

Tags: android, showcaseview

I have a strange error when exiting the app and reentering it ,the `ShowcaseView` is not centered,I use this code in a Fragment.
This my code for :

```
target = new ViewTarget(iv_QR);
            if (showcase == null) {
                Button button = new Button(getContext());
                button.setText("Got it !");
                button.setEnabled(false);
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                showcase = new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme2)
                        .replaceEndButton(button)
                        .setTarget(target)
                        .withMaterialShowcase()
                        .setContentTitle("QR Scan(Required)")
                        .setContentText("Please press the QR icon to scan the QR")
                        .build();
```

and this is my xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragments.QRFragment">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_QR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@mipmap/qricon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am attaching an Image:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `android:gravity="center"` in your `RelativeLayout`? In that case you can remove `android:layout_centerHorizontal` and `layout_ centerVertical`.

Comment: it doesn't help @REG1

Comment: when the aplication first starts it is centered,but when i quit it and enter it again this problem happens

Comment: I figured out what the problem is,i am trying to show it before onCreateView sometimes,i show it when a certain event occurs,I need to think how to show it after onCreateView was called @REG1

Comment: So I updated my answer based on your discovery.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming that the problem is caused by the `ShowcaseView` being created before `onCreateView()` has returned, consider creating and showing your `ShowcaseView` in the [`onActivityCreated()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) method of your Fragment.

[Here is some sample code](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/amlcurran/showcaseview/sample/FragmentDemoActivity.java) of `ShowcaseView` being used with Fragments, try to implement it in your own code. As you can see it also uses the method `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help even when i have the view @REG1

Comment: Can you post more code (including the updates), i.e. show the entire method from which you instantiate the ShowcaseView and all other code related to it?

Comment: Thats a lot of code,i will try to explain my self better:I use AppIntro with 3 Fragments ,I use show case with the first fragment and everything is ok there,when I am done with the first Fragment I want to move to next Fragment (the one you see in the picture)  ,the problem  when Using onActivityCreated() It shows the showcase immediately ,because showcase.build() displays it  .now The showcases are one on the other @REG1

Comment: So when do you want the showcase to be shown? Are you saying that the "no centered" problem is resolved using onActivityCreated(), but that the showcase is shown too early?

Comment: Yes,exactly when the first Fragment is done i want the ShowcaseView to be shown @REG1

Comment: @Maximtoyberman So place the `showcase.build()` method into the `onSlideChanged()` method of your `AppIntro` class. This will mean the the showcase is only shown when you select the desired fragment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115223/discussion-between-maxim-toyberman-and-reg1).